# All my Provisioning Profiles are created with error status

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning, provisioning-profile

Something really strange is going on here. I bought a new Mac last week, and I am now coding on this new machine. I completely forgot to export my Developer Profile from my old Mac, and now that's gone for good, so I am unable to export it for import on to this new machine. Thus, I revoked both my distribution and development certificates in the provisioning portal.

I then followed [these](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG6) steps to "start fresh."

Now, I have new certificates generated from my new Mac, and in Organiser > Devices > "Teams" (left hand side), I can see both iOS Development and Distribution there. I can also see my new certificates in Keychain Access.

Here's where I'm lost. In the Provisioning Portal, every new Profile that I have made, as well as the *iOS Team Provisioning Profile* (managed by Xcode) has the status "**error**" - *not "invalid".* Therefore, I cannot create any provisioning profiles to a) submit to the app store or b) test on my devices.

A couple more notes (not sure if these are linked to the problem) -

- In Xcode, when attempting to submit to App Store, I get "No Identities are available for signing" and clicking "download identities from Xcode" doesn't help the situation
- I have not changed any App IDs since changing my certificates

Thanks again for your help, despite quite a lengthy read!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am also facing this problem from morning and got a message from Apple:

> **We are performing maintenance on the provisioning service. All provisioning requests will remain in pending status until maintenance is complete, at which time all pending requests will be automatically processed.**

So keep patient.

Comment: Wow, that's really weird, I haven't received that message just yet. I'll wait and see what happens then. Thanks!

Comment: Log in to developer.apple.com you will find the message.

Comment: Turns out you were right and my profiles ended up working. Although I never saw the error message despite logging into the portal etc.

Answer (score 0):

Either your certificates are not correctly installed on your new mac or the provisioning profiles installed are from your previous certificates which you have revoked now. Did you re-new your provisioning profiles with the new certificates?

Comment: Yeah, since I have revoked my old certificates, all my new profiles have been created with the new certificates. Also, I've tried manual install as well as an Xcode install of the certificates, to have the same result, so I assume they're correctly installed.

Comment: Did install the new profiles in your mac again? if yes, then the only problem i see is with the certificates. They are not correctly installed.

Comment: The profiles are being created with an Error, as I said, so I can't actually install the profiles on my Mac. As Adbullah pointed out below, perhaps it's a problem on Apple's end, so I will wait it out and see what happens. Thanks for your ideas though!